# How can I continue to listen changes of 2 flowable list in the combined list?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have two Flowable list
and I need to combine them ,apply some functions and get Flowable list
the initial Flowable lists represent data from DB 
and the idea is that when in the DB could be changes the combined list could be changed as well as the inputs are changed.
I guess zip isn’t the right approach as it once works complete it’s job and doesn’t continue to emit changes. 
My question what could be alternative of zip where I could combine 2 lists ,apply some functions and continue to listen updates

```
Flowable.zip(shoppingListsRepository.loadCommonArticles(), shoppingListsRepository.loadShoppingListItems(shoppingListId),
BiFunction<List<CommonArticle>, List<ShoppingListItem>, List<CommonArticle>> { 
commonArticles, shoppingListItems ->
//apply some filters on these two list and return result
  items
});


fun loadCommonArticles(): Flowable<List<CommonArticle>> {
return shoppingListDao.loadCommonArticles()
}

 fun loadShoppingListItems(shoppingListId: 
 Int):Flowable<List<ShoppingListItem>> {
  return shoppingListDao.loadShoppingListItems(shoppingListId)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [`Flowable.combineLatest(stream1, stream2, combineBiFunc)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#combineLatest-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-org.reactivestreams.Publisher-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-).
If stream1 ends, stream2 will still generate emissions with the last known list from stream1 (and vice versa). In the combineBiFunc, you can decide what to do with the updated data.